# When decoding json i get error Unexpected character

Tags: flutter, dart

I have json file with the following data in it:

```
{
  "item1": "value1",
  "item2": "value2",
  "item3": "value3"
}
```

I also have `Items()` class in a seperate file which has the method `getItems()` method which loads the json file:

```
class Items {
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getItems() async {
    String jsonData =
        await rootBundle.loadString('assets/items.json');
    Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(jsonData);
    return data;
  }
}
```

I also have a scaffold to show the items with `ListView.builder`. I first use `setState` to assign the returned value of `Items().getItems()` to the field `items`. I then use the value of the field inside the `LisView.builder`

```
class ItemList extends StatefulWidget {
  const ItemList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ItemListState createState() => _ItemListState();
}

class _ItemListState extends State<ItemList> {
  late String items = '';
  setItems() async {
    final item = await Items().getItems();
    setState(() {
      items = item.toString();
    });
  }

  @override
  initState() {
    setItems();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(items);
    debugPrint(data.toString());
    debugPrint(items);

    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: data.keys.length,
        itemBuilder: (c, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text("key " + data.keys.toList()[index]),
            subtitle: Text("value " + data.values.toList()[index]),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am able to show the list of items when i place string hardcoded like this :

`Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode('{ "item1": "#48f542","item2": "value2","item3": "value3"}');`

But i get an error when i use the field `items` like this: `Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(items);`

I get the error `Unexpected character (at character 2) {item1: value1, item2: value2, item3: value3... ^`

Both ways should work because it is basicly the same data types. I don't know what i am doing wrong.

**Edit**

I want to avoid using models because in my use case for example if i add another item key in the json object then i also need to change the model.

Comment: maybe you need to do items.toString()?

Comment: i now get error: `type String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. The reason why i got the error is because i used `jsonDecode` on a bad format. The format was `{item: value}` instead of `{"item": "value"}`. So the solution was to use `jsonEncode` inside `setState`

```
setState(() {
      clientSettings = jsonEncode(client);});
```

When i did `jsonEncode` before `jsonDecode` my error was gone i can show the list of items.

**Edit**

The problem with this solution is that you run with the error: `Unexpected end of input (at character 1)`

I made another OP where the problem for this was resolved: [Unexpected end of input (at character 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71397862/unexpected-end-of-input-at-character-1)

Credit to: https://stackoverflow.com/users/17637096/b%c3%a9linda-g-freitas

Answer (score 1):

Your `getItems()` function returns `Map<String, dynamic>`, but in `ItemList` class your items is `String`. You should change
late `String items = '';` to late `Map<String, dynamic> items = '';`.