# Unexpected end of input (at character 1)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have json file with the following data in it:

```
{
  "item1": "value1",
  "item2": "value2",
  "item3": "value3"
}
```

I also have `Items()` class in a seperate file which has the method `getItems()` method which loads the json file:

```
class Items {
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getItems() async {
    String jsonData =
        await rootBundle.loadString('assets/items.json');
    Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(jsonData);
    return data;
  }
}
```

I also have a scaffold to show the items with `ListView.builder`. I first use `setState` to assign the returned value of `Items().getItems()` to the field `items`. I then use the value of the field inside the `LisView.builder`

```
class ItemList extends StatefulWidget {
  const ItemList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ItemListState createState() => _ItemListState();
}

class _ItemListState extends State<ItemList> {
  late String items = '';
  setItems() async {
    final item = await Items().getItems();
    setState(() {
      items = jsonEncode(item);
    });
  }

  @override
  initState() {
    setItems();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(items);
    debugPrint(data.toString());
    debugPrint(items);

    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: data.keys.length,
        itemBuilder: (c, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text("key " + data.keys.toList()[index]),
            subtitle: Text("value " + data.values.toList()[index]),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am able to show the list of items on the `Scaffold()` but i still get the error: `Unexpected end of input (at character 1)`

When i click on the error it highlights on the `jsonDecode(items)`. So something goes wrong there but i don't know what.

Comment: You don't need to jsonEncode your item in setState. it should be already Map<string, string> type. And Also you don't need to jsonDecode the items in build again.

Comment: When i remove `jsonDecode` i get error `A value of type 'String' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'` when i hover on `clientSettings` on build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to simplify your code like this

```
class _ItemListState extends State<ItemList> {
  Map<String, dynamic> data = {};
  setItems() async {
    await Items().getItems().then((value) => setState(() => data = value));
  }

  @override
  initState() {
    setItems();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    debugPrint(data);
  //rest of code ...
}
```

and check if you still get the error.

Comment: I get another error: `type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' of 'function result'`

Comment: Never mind i had to to do a hot restart. Thank you this worked. Also i didn't know you can simplify the code like that

Comment: I only wonder if you could give me explaination on why the error occured?

Comment: The error occurs because at first `items = ''` since you wrote `late String items = '';` then in the `initState()`, `setItems()` set the new value so there is no more error that is why your `ListView` was rendered. `jsonDecode` can't parse an empty `String`. I hope my explanation is clear.